# using value from select in reactive form - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I want to use the value from a selected value, I want to use the attributes from that object to use as a min and max value. With the method I am trying now the min and max values do not get updated when i select a category

```
<form [formGroup]="brewingMethod" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input
          matInput
          aria-label="name"
          placeholder="name"
          type="text"
          formControlName="name"
          required
        />
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select
          aria-label="category"
          formControlName="category"
          placeholder="category"
        >
          <mat-option
            *ngFor="let category of (categories$ | async)"
            [value]="category"
          >
            {{ category.name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
        <p>temperature(°C): </p>
        <mat-slider  min="{{brewingMethod.get('category')['minTemperature']}}"  max="{{brewingMethod.get('category')['maxTemperature']}}" step="0.5" value="{{brewingMethod.get('category')}}" thumbLabel tickInterval="1" valueLabelDisplay="on"></mat-slider>
        <p>ratio(g/L): </p><br>
        <input
          formControlName="ratio"
          aria-label="ratio"
          placeholder="ratio"
          type="range"
          min="{{brewingMethod.get('category')['minRatio']}}"
          max="{{brewingMethod.get('category')['maxRatio']}}"
          required
        /><br>
        <p>grindSize:</p>
        <input
          formControlName="grindSize"
          aria-label="grind size"
          placeholder="grind size"
          type="range"
          min="{{brewingMethod.get('category')['minGrindSize']}}"
          max="{{brewingMethod.get('category')['maxGrindSize']}}"
          required
        />
        <mat-error
          *ngIf="
            brewingMethod.get('name')['errors']?.required &&
            brewingMethod.get('name').touched
          "
        >
        {{ getErrorMessage(brewingMethod.get("name")["errors"]) }}
      </mat-error>
      <br>
      <button
        type="submit"
        mat-raised-button
        [disabled]="!brewingMethod.valid"
      >
        add brewing method
      </button>
    </form>
```

category holds the min and max value's that I need in the range slider, when I select a category the range sliders do not update

Comment: `brewingMethod.get('category').value.minTemperature` you forgot the "value"

Comment: I did try this before and just tried it out again:

`<mat-slider data-cy="temperature" min="{{brewingMethod.get('category').value.minTemperature}}"  max="{{brewingMethod.get('category').value.maxTemperature}}" step="0.5" value="{{brewingMethod.get('category').value.temperature}}" thumbLabel tickInterval="1" valueLabelDisplay="on"></mat-slider>`

but this did not work aswell

Comment: take a look to this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-puaone?file=src/app/slider-overview-example.html. I add in select a function `checkRange` to give always a value to ratio between the selected values

Comment: I tried modifying your example to my app, I posted it in a stackblitz so it is more readable this also isn't working just yet because it needs te be a level deeper so Category has a Temperature and Temperature has the minTemperature and MaxTemperature
[stackblitz so you can read more easily](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-duk6yu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: after testing some more it does set the min and max value it just sets the value itself in a weird default spot